# Samsung UEFI brick

Tags: boot, samsung

I think I might have bricked the computer while trying to boot it from a USB stick.

I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and the computer (Samsung NP550P5C) had come with preinstalled Windows 8. I clean installed Windows 7 by changing the boot option from UEFI to CMS OS.
Yesterday I was trying to reinstall Ubuntu but this time through a USB stick, and CMS boot option could not recognize the USB so I changed the option back to UEFI.
Ever since then, I cannot even go into BIOS options to change it back to CMS OS but I can see the Samsung logo after powerup,and black screen after that.

Does this mean that it is bricked?

Is there any other way of fixing it other than sending it to Samsung for motherboard replacement?

Note: I know this might not be the best place to ask such a question, but it is all I could think of at the moment.

Edit: Forgot to add that when I see the Samsung logo, the usual F2 and F4 options do not show there, if they did, I could just switch back to CSM and all would be well (I guess).

Comment: I think I am facing the same problem, it can not detect my bootable USB at startup.

Comment: You motherboard is bricked. This is a bug with Samsung UEFI when booting Linux in UEFI mode because it fills the firmware NVRAM

Answer (score 1):

It has been months since this was solved but I think posting the solution will help others who experience this in the future.

The simple thing is, although you cannot see the usual F2 and F4 options, it seems they are not gone anywhere.

If, for any reason, you stop seeing these options during startup, just press F2 (maybe keep pressing it) as soon as you power up the laptop. It will take you to BIOS settings where you can revert whatever caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to open the laptop remove baterry & the pin on the motherboard next to battery to reset bios wait few sec like 20 sec put all again as before & turn on your computer enter bios & set all over again even the time.

Answer (score 0):

also at this time you have program make bootable usb with windows 7 8 8.1 & linux. like rufus program. create a bootable usb with GRT partition. them when you have both installed go to windows download easyBCD program & add a entry for dual boot windows & linux for ex. of course i forgot to say with UEFI enable & secure boot enable.